# Getting the root element of xml file in linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I am using linq. Here is my document structure:

```
<t totalWord="2" creationDate="15.01.2016 02:33:37" ver="1">
    <k kel_id="1000">
        <kel>7</kel>
        <kel_gs>0</kel_gs>
        <kel_bs>0</kel_bs>
        <km>Ron/INT-0014</km>
        <kel_za>10.01.2016 02:28:05</kel_za>
        <k_det kel_nit="12" kel_res="4" KelSID="1" >
            <kel_ac>ac7</kel_ac>
        </k_det>
    </k>
    <k kel_id="1001">
        <kel>whitte down</kel>
        <kel_gs>0</kel_gs>
        <kel_bs>0</kel_bs>
        <km>Ron/INT-0014</km>
        <kel_za>15.01.2016 02:33:37</kel_za>
        <k_det kel_nit="12" kel_res="4" KelSID="1">
            <kel_ac>to gradually make something smaller by making it by taking parts away</kel_ac>
            <kel_kc>cut down</kel_kc>
            <kel_oc>The final key to success is to turn your interviewer into a champion: someone who is willing to go to bat for you when the hiring committee meets to whittle down the list.</kel_oc>
            <kel_trac >adım adım parçalamak</kel_trac>
        </k_det>
    </k>
</t>
```

This is a dictionary. *t* is root. *k* is word. When a new word arrives, *totalword* attribute and *creationDate* shall update accordingly. I have to get *t* node, get its attribute and save it. I have written the code above:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
XElement rootElement = xdoc.Root;
XElement kokNode = rootElement.Element("t");
XAttribute toplamSayi = kokNode.Attribute("totalWord");
```

*kokNode* comes null. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `<t>` is the root, just set `var kokNode = xdoc.Root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdoc.Root` will return the root element, which is your `t` element in this case.

`rootElement.Element("t")` will therefore return `null` as `t` has no child `t` element.

Either use `xdoc.Root` or `xdoc.Element("t")`, i.e.:

```
var tomplamSayi = xdoc.Root.Attribute("totalWord")
```

or:

```
var tomplamSayi = xdoc.Element("t").Attribute("totalWord")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
string totalword;
foreach (XElement x in xdoc.Descendants("t")){
   totalword= x.Attribute("totalword").Value.ToString().Trim(); // Get the totalword attribute's value
}
```

Comment: Thank you for three of the answer. Since I can not set multiple answer as a answer, I set the most recent one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"totalWord" is an attribute of the root element which is `t`, not an attribute of `k`. So simply get the attribute from the root element like this:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

XElement rootElement = xdoc.Root;

XAttribute toplamSayi = rootElement.Attribute("totalWord");
```